How does OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE work?
I am trying to simulate the Steane code with circuit level noise using stim. I would like to use pymatching to correct errors. My circuit has detectors but does not include any logical observables to feed into this decoder. I saw that the Getting Started page had a section on adding a logical observable to the repetition code using: "OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-1]" but I'm not sure how simply adding the last measurement to observable 0 tracks the parity of the left-most data qubit throughout all rounds of the sample. Could someone explain how this works? How can I adapt this to my Steane code circuit?


I'm not sure how simply adding the last measurement to observable 0 tracks the parity of the left-most data qubit throughout all rounds of the sample

The qubit being measured existed during all those rounds. Errors on that qubit during those rounds would propagate forward into the measurement, flipping the observable. Thus the observable's error sensitivity stretches back to those rounds.

How can I adapt this to my Steane code circuit?

If you are doing transversal measurements with M or MX on every data qubit, add an OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE instruction targeting the set of measurements corresponding to the qubits of the logical observable in that basis.
If you are doing phenom measurements with MPP, append an additional MPP instruction that directly measures the observable and then OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-1] right after that measurement.
